# I want to create a code in python or Matlab to divide a sequence into pairs and give the values to these pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, matlab, loops

I want to create a program in python or Matlab to divide a sequence into pairs such that first letter pairs with all other letters and give the values to these pairs. Example
"ABCBADD"
AB=1
AC=1/2
AB=1/3
AA=1/4
AD=1/5
AD=1/6
Now skip first letter of sequence
"BCBADD"
BC=1
BB=1/2
BA=1/3
BD=1/4
BD=1/5
Now skip first and so on
"CBADD"
and add same pair values as AB=1+1/3,AD=1/5+1/6,BD=1/4+1/5
I will be thankful to help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do with two loop:

```
s = "ABCBADD"   
output = [(s[i] + c, 1 /(idx + 1))   for i in range(len(s) -1) for idx, c in enumerate(s[i+1:])]
```

output:

```
print(output)

[('AB', 1.0),
 ('AC', 0.5),
 ('AB', 0.3333333333333333),
 ('AA', 0.25),
 ('AD', 0.2),
 ('AD', 0.16666666666666666),
 ('BC', 1.0),
 ('BB', 0.5),
 ('BA', 0.3333333333333333),
 ('BD', 0.25),
 ('BD', 0.2),
 ('CB', 1.0),
 ('CA', 0.5),
 ('CD', 0.3333333333333333),
 ('CD', 0.25),
 ('BA', 1.0),
 ('BD', 0.5),
 ('BD', 0.3333333333333333),
 ('AD', 1.0),
 ('AD', 0.5),
 ('DD', 1.0)]
```

Comment: I'm not getting this output, any package or commode is required and if I extend the string up to one thousand letters, I will get the result? A commode to add the values of same pairs (AB=1+0.33, AD=0.2+0.166+1.0+0.5,...)?

Comment: @RiazHussainKhan The list was created, but if was with assumption that you print the output to see the output. I edited the code to store as output list and you see the results if you print them, or run in in interactive mode like in ipython or jupyter.

Comment: @upto 1000 should be fine since you output will be sum(range(n)) ~500K element,